# Parse Saved HTML File VBA

Tags: html, vba

I have a HTML file that is saved locally on the desktop which contains a table of statistics from which I need to pull specific data, paste it into a excel workbook table and then email it.

I've got the rest of the process working, I'm just struggling to figure out how to parse the html file and all other examples I've seen are parsing a website rather than a locally saved html file.

Apologies if this is a bit of beginner question but I'm finding it hard to make sense of the other examples I've seen.

thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Assign it to an htmldocument var like xmlhttp.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51114836/edit) to include more information.  Would you please add the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: To repeat Jeeped's comment create an HTMLDocument object and assign the HTML you  have to it. Then target the table by whatever suitable identifying characteristic it has e.g id or table tag (with index). If you share your code attempts and relevant HTML we can better advise you on resolving any issues.

Comment: You may also be able to open the file in Excel and parse the data from there.

Comment: http://codevba.com/visual-basic-source-code/vb-read/read_string_of_text_or_html_from_fullpath.htm#.W19QwO4vzX4

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for your examples and pointing me in the right direction ! The example posted below copies the data from a HTML file stored on the users desktop and pastes it into a new worksheet in Excel.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ParseHTML()

Dim URL           As String
Dim IE            As InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc       As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument             'Document object
Dim eleColtr      As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection    'Element collection for tr tags
Dim eleColtd      As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection    'Element collection for td tags
Dim htmlTables    As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection    'Element collection for table tags
Dim eleRow        As MSHTML.IHTMLElement              'Row elements
Dim eleCol        As MSHTML.IHTMLElement              'Column elements
Dim wksOut        As Worksheet
Dim rngOut        As Range
Dim intTableIndex As Integer
Dim intRowIndex   As Integer
Dim intColIndex   As Integer

URL = Environ("userProfile") & "\desktop\FileName.HTML"

'Open InternetExplorer.
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

'Navigate to URL.
With IE
    .navigate URL
    .Visible = False


'Extract html information to objects.
Set htmldoc = IE.document
Set htmlTables = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
Set eleColtr = htmlTables(intTableIndex).getElementsByTagName("tr")

'Extract table to a new blank worksheet.
On Error Resume Next
Set wksOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WorksheetName")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wksOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    wksOut.Name = "WorksheetName"
End If
With wksOut
    .Cells.Clear
    .Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
    .Cells.ColumnWidth = 2
End With
On Error GoTo 0

'This section populates Excel
intRowIndex = 0
For Each eleRow In eleColtr
    Set eleColtd = htmlTables(intTableIndex).getElementsByTagName("tr")(intRowIndex).getElementsByTagName("td") 'get all the td elements in that specific tr
    Set rngOut = wksOut.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    intColIndex = 0
    For Each eleCol In eleColtd
        rngOut.Offset(0, intColIndex) = eleCol.innerText
        intColIndex = intColIndex + 1
    Next eleCol
    intRowIndex = intRowIndex + 1
Next eleRow

wksOut.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit


'Cleanup
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
Set htmldoc = Nothing
Set htmlTables = Nothing
Set eleColtr = Nothing
Set eleColtd = Nothing
Set wksOut = Nothing
Set rngOut = Nothing

End With

End Sub
```

Please note that excel may throw a Runtime Error Automation Error on line:

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
```

If this happens try setting InternetExplorer integrity to Medium:

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

If you need more information regarding InternetExplorer Integrity please see
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/03/default-integrity-level-and-automation/

As Tim mentioned I could open the file in excel and copy and paste the values which runs a lot faster:

```
Sub CopyHTML()

dim Wb as Workbook
dim Ws as Worksheet

Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Ws = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Opens html file and copies range
Workbooks.Open (Environ("userProfile") & "\desktop\FileName.html")
Range("A1:AJ21").Select
Selection.Copy

'pastes range in cell B5 on active workbook
Wb.Activate
Range("B5").Select
Ws.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("FileName.html").Close
```

Thanks for the advice Tim !